# how to add key values in list of object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, addition

beginner needs advice.
How can i add values from list of objects
if I have

```js
var arr = [{key1: value1}, {key2: value2}];
```

where I want to add value 1 + value 2 and store it in another variable. 
edit: given the value 1 and value 2 are numbers. There can be 1-4 objects in array.

Comment: Well, in this case `var anotherVariable = arr[0].key1 + arr[1].key2`.

Comment: Do you want to sum all the values in the array, also are keys , key1 and key2 equal

Comment: This will work onlz if there are always 2 objects in the array right? what if there can be 1-4 object(always same format), If there can be 1-4 objects in array, should I do for cycle? if so, how? please. Sorrz should have specified this

Comment: You're still in time to amend your question with this new information. Please add them.

Comment: @MichaelAnděl Look at my answer I have updated it

Comment: question updated. @Andam your solution kinda worked. It did added two values togather, but then it multiplied it by 2 or added final value to its self?

Comment: @MichaelAnděl I have added 2 other objects to my answer they are producing correct result.

Comment: question updated. @Andam It works like a charm in a console, but somehow in my process it does not. It propably will be something in enviroment.  Anyway big thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have same property name like this

```js
var arr = [{key1: 1}, {key1: 2}, {key1: 2}, {key1: 2}];
var sum = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
  sum += arr[i].key1;
  
console.log(sum);
```

if not something like this

```js
var arr = [{key1: 1}, {key1: 2}, {key3: 2}, {key4: 2}];
var sum = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
  sum += Object.values(arr[i])[0];
  
console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to push in same array, you can do like this

```js
var arr = [{
  key1: 1
}, {
  key2: 3
}];

var sum = 0; // Create a variable to store the sum
// loop over it and get each object
arr.forEach(function(item) {
  // again using for ..in loop since key name is different
  for (var keys in item) {
    sum += item[keys]
  }
})
// pushing the value to the array
arr.push({
  key3: sum
});

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

For accessing array elements you need to use indexes, then you can use keys for accessing vaues

`arr[0]` will return first object of array.

`arr[0].key1` of `arr[0]['key1']` will return value of key1 in first element of array.

Your code will something like this

```
value3 = arr[0].key1 + arr[1].key2
arr.push({key3: value3})
```

Or You need to make loops for iterating in all elements.